# Подключение к Steam OpenID через Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, steam-web-api, openid

Необходимо реализовать на сайте, написанном на Ruby on Rails, поддержку авторизации через Steam, который предоставляет OpenID. Рекомендуемый сайтом OpenID гем - openid_connect (остальные больше не разрабатываются). Я сделал запрашивающую часть так:

```
def openid_client
  @openid_client ||= OpenIDConnect::Client.new(
    identifier: ENV['STEAM_ID'],
    secret: ENV['STEAM_WEB_API_KEY'],
    redirect_uri: root_url + '/login/callback',
    scheme: 'http',
    host: 'steamcommunity.com',
    authorization_endpoint: '/openid/login',
    token_endpoint: '/openid/tokens',
    userinfo_endpoint: '/openid/userinfo'
  )
end

def login
  session[:nonce] = SecureRandom.hex 16
  auth_uri = openid_client.authorization_uri(
    scope: [:profile],
    state: session[:nonce],
    nonce: session[:nonce]
  )
  redirect_to auth_uri
end
```

То есть как описано в документации. 
STEAM_ID - поле Domain, которое я заполнял при получении API ключа, STEAM_WEB_API_KEY - собственно, сам API ключ.  Запрос получается такой:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?client_id=myclientid&nonce=528a94fcfa07543db812b952b505be37&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%2Flogin%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=profile+openid&state=3becd4f10ec8444235fa8ac843a64573
```

Steam перенаправляет запрос на steamcommunity.com, то есть, скорее всего, это означает ошибку. Что я могу делать не так?

P. S. Смотрел запрос с другого сайта со Steam авторизацией - там они отправляют только realm и кучу ссылок на спецификации, NS и подобное с префиксами openid. Я совсем запутался, в какую сторону мне делать.

Comment: Есть [не слишком старый `omniauth-steam`](https://github.com/reu/omniauth-steam), а OmniAuth пользоваться на порядок проще. Рассмотрите такой вариант.